# Laravel 5.4: logout keep redirecting me to an unexisting URI

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I'm learning laravel 5.4 from laracast and in episode 19, where I should create a user session system.
So, for now, I can register a new user, log him in but I can't logout. this method keeps redirecting me to an unexisting uri "app.dev/home".
Here is the method:

```
public function destroy()
{
    Auth::logout();
    return redirect('/');
}
```

and here are all the routes

```
Route::get('/', 'PostsController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('/posts/{post}', 'PostsController@show');
Route::get('/post/create', 'PostsController@create');
Route::post('/posts', 'PostsController@store');
Route::post('/post/{post}/comment', 'CommentsController@store');
Route::get('/tasks', 'TasksController@index');
Route::get('/tasks/{task}', 'TasksController@show');
Route::get('about', function () {
return view('about');
});
// Auth::routes();
//Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
Route::get('/register', 'RegistrationController@show');
Route::post('/register', 'RegistrationController@store');
Route::get('login', 'SessionController@create');
Route::post('login', 'SessionController@store');
Route::get('/logout', 'SessionController@destroy');
```

Comment: btw "Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');" is commented

Comment: What URL is it redirecting to?

Comment: Share that `unexisting uri.` ?

Comment: it keeps redirecting me to app.dev/home

Comment: Try to redirect to `return redirect('/login');` and check if it works. Maybe it is redirecting to `/` but the user needs to be authenticated, so it is redirecting again to a default page.

Comment: @Laerte no still not working, I don't have a middleware preventing users to visit the homepage